# Reportlab - How do I group section header and table row to prevent widows/orphans

Tags: python, reportlab

Reportlab KeepWithNext isn't working for me and unlike previous posts I've seen I'm not using zero width fields.  I'm new to reportlab so maybe I'm doing something wrong, if so please let me know.

A section heading is left at the bottom of a frame instead of being kicked to the next frame.  I've simplified my code as much as I can and still reproduce the problem, my apologies for posting so much code.  I've tried to find a workaround but just got even more confused.

I will greatly appreciate any pointers.

Thank you.

This code will reproduce the problem:

```
from reportlab.platypus import BaseDocTemplate, Frame, Paragraph, Table, TableStyle, PageTemplate
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import legal, letter, landscape, portrait
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_JUSTIFY, TA_LEFT, TA_CENTER, TA_RIGHT
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
import  os, sys, json
   
def format_time(e):
    return(e['time'])
def format_event(e):          # format event name, address, notes
    return( f"<b>{e['name']}</b><br/>{e['location']}<br/>{e['notes']}")
def format_region(e):
    return(f"<b>{e['region']}</b>")  

def get_events(conf, events):
    styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
    styleE = ParagraphStyle('events',
                           fontName = 'Helvetica',
                           fontSize= 10,
                           parent = styles['Normal'],
                           allowWidows = 0,
                           allowOrphans = 0,
                           alignment= TA_LEFT)
                           
    styleH = ParagraphStyle('heading',
                           fontName = 'Helvetica-Bold',
                           fontSize= 12,
                           parent=styles['Normal'],
                           allowWidows = 0,
                           allowOrphans = 0,
                           alignment= TA_CENTER,
                           keepWithNext = 1)    

    sections = []                       # split events into lists by sections
    for d in range(len(conf['sections'])):
        sections.append([x for x in events if x['day'] == d])
    data = []
    for i in range(len(sections)):              # add heading row
        h = Paragraph(f"<b>{conf['sections'][i]}</b><br/>" , styleH)
        data.append([None, h, None]) 
        for e in sections[i]:         # format event    
            data.append([
                Paragraph(format_time(e), styleE),
                Paragraph(format_event(e), styleE),
                Paragraph(format_region(e), styleE)
            ])
    return(data)
   
def show_events(conf, data):
    doc = BaseDocTemplate(
                    sys.stdout.buffer,
                    pagesize=landscape(legal),
                    leftMargin = .05*inch,
                    rightMargin = .05*inch,
                    topMargin = .05*inch,
                    bottomMargin = .05*inch,
                    allowSplitting=1,
                    showBoundary=0
                    )
 
    tablestyle =  TableStyle([
            ('TOPPADDING', (0,0),(-1,-1), 0),    
            ('BOTTOMPADDING', (0,0),(-1,-1), 2),
            ('LEFTPADDING', (0,0),(-1,-1), 0),
            ('RIGHTPADDING', (0,0),(-1,-1),3),
            ('VALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'TOP'),
            ])                  
   
    frame_count = 4
    frame_width = doc.width / frame_count
    frame_height = doc.height
   
    frames = []    
    for f in range(frame_count):  
        leftMargin = doc.leftMargin + f*frame_width
        column = Frame(leftMargin, doc.bottomMargin, frame_width, frame_height)
        frames.append(column)
         
    template = PageTemplate(id = None, frames=frames)
    doc.addPageTemplates(template)

    elements = []            
    col_widths = []
    for x in conf['col_widths']:
        col_widths.append(x*frame_width)
    t = Table(data, col_widths)  
    t.setStyle(tablestyle)
    elements.append(t)
    doc.build(elements)

def main():
    conf = {
        "col_widths":               [0.17, 0.62, 0.21],
        "sections":                 ["SUNDAY",
                                "MONDAY",
                                "TUESDAY",
                                "WEDNESDAY",
                                "THURSDAY",
                                "FRIDAY",
                                "SATURDAY"
                                ]
    }
    events = []
    for i in range(7):         # generate dummy test data
        for j in range(14):
            events.append({"day": i, "time": "7:30 am", "name": "Big Splat", "location": "US-441 near Sedona", "region": "Arizona", "notes": "witness reported was ugly"})
       
    data = get_events(conf, events)
    show_events(conf, data)
   
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I also tried changing to keepTogether:
I tried KeepTogether :

```
        h = Paragraph(f"<b>{conf['sections'][i]}</b><br/>" , styleH)
        hdr = [None, h, None]
        e = sections[i].pop(0)
        ev =[
                Paragraph(format_time(e), styleE),
                Paragraph(format_event(e), styleE),
                Paragraph(format_region(e), styleE)
            ]
        data.append(KeepTogether([hdr, ev]))
```

but got  TypeError: 'KeepTogether' object is not iterable and couldn't figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

Wound up keeping section headers out of table.  For each section, add header with keepWithNext then add table of 1 row for keepWithNext to bind to.  Then add another table with remaining rows from section.  Tacky but it's the only way I could get it to work.

```
    elements = []                   
    for i in range(len(sections)):   
        elements.append(Paragraph(f"{conf['sections'][i]}" , styleH))  # section heading
        t = Table([sections[i].pop(0)], col_widths)     # 1 row table for header keepWithNext   
        t.setStyle(tablestyle)
        elements.append(t)
        
        t = Table(sections[i], col_widths)  
        t.setStyle(tablestyle)
        elements.append(t)
        
    doc.build(elements)
```